# Button in UIView is unresponsive

Tags: swift, button, uiview

I'm trying to learn swift on my own and following the Apple developer tutorial (yes i'm also watching youtube vids but trying to learn on all angles).

I've gotten to "Implement a Custom Control" and at this point copied and pasted all their code in the custom view

```
import UIKit

class starRating: UIView {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 44, height: 44))
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        button.addTarget(self, action: "ratingButtonTapped:", forControlEvents: .TouchDown)
        addSubview(button)
    }

    func ratingButtonTapped(button: UIButton) {
        print("Button pressed ")
    }
}
```

and have followed all steps before hand and the button nested in the view is unresponsive. User interaction is enabled

don't really know what I'm doing wrong

Please help! 
Thank you

Comment: does adding 'self.userInteractionEnabled = true' inside `init()` work for you?

Comment: `userInteractionEnabled` is `true` by default for `UIView` though. But maybe he has set it to `false` somewhere by accident.

Comment: no doesn't change anything =\

Comment: Usually for UIButtons you want the controlEvents to be `.TouchUpInside`.  I'm not sure if that'd make the difference or not, but you might give it a try.

Comment: thanks just tried it. no change

Comment: how have you implemented addSubview() method?

Comment: yup, third line of code up from the bottom

Comment: Have you confirmed that `addTarget` is being run? If you're creating the view on the fly using `init(frame frame: CGRect)`, then `init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` will not run.